# Difference between asp:button and html's button

Tags: asp.net, button

I'm learning asp.net. I have question about example buttons

I can use two types of button.

```
   <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

or

```
   <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

What are the main differences between the two?

Comment: One is a server control the other a client control.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is a server control (the asp button) that when rendered on the page includes javascript that handles the postback logic, as well as being exposed to your code-behinds as a control you can address by its ID. The Html control is platform agnostic, and is rendered by your browser as just a button. That button will raise click events but will not POST your form.

Comment: but when i want to write function for click on html buttons I must write it in javaScript, yes?

Comment: @nirmus -- In the case of the asp control you can write it as back-end asp.net code, or front end code by including a "OnClientClick" handler in the button's declaration. In either case (asp or html), you can wire up an "OnClick" handler either in-line (thumbs down) or with jQuery (thumbs up).

Answer (score 1):

Each  click will make a round trip to server, which should not occur everytime. HTML Button is much lighter and should be used to make client - logic like client validation, run client script,etc....
ASP button will makes a POST everytime you click, html button do not.

Comment: but when i want to write function for click on html buttons I must write it in javaScript, yes?

Comment: If your onClick function is a complicated one, you should. If it just show some links, you can do it with html only. Of course you can link a click-event with some php script file, if you want to do it.