# Is it possible to replace an asp:button with a HTML element

Tags: asp.net, forms, button

I'm using asp forms and wanted to know if it's possible to replace the standard buttons with HTML elements that are styled using CSS.

My login page uses a standard button

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Login" 
    onclick="LoginButton_Click" />
```

linked to code behind (C#) which performs the login check.

I've seen some nice buttons implemented using the HTML `<button>` element and styled with CSS which can have features such as images and roll over highlighting. The basic HTML looks like this

```
<button type="submit" class="positive" onclick ="...">
    <img src="/icons/tick.png" alt=""/> 
    Login
</button>
```

I've seen another question discussing the [Difference between asp:button and html's button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813760/difference-between-aspbutton-and-htmls-button) so I understand the `<button>` element is not a drop-in replacement but I'd like to know if the `asp:button` can be replaced and still call the `LoginButton_Click` C# code behind?

**EDIT:**
Although I'm using ASP I don't mind using some client side javascript if necessary.

The buttons I saw which got me thinking about this were found here: [Rediscovering the Button Element](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/)

**EDIT 2:**
I tried the [answer from XIII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8244064/243925) using the `LinkButton` asp control and that worked, rendering the button as I wanted and activating the C# when clicked

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LoginBtn" CssClass="button positive"
        OnClick="LoginButton_Click" runat="server">
    <img src="/icons/tick.png" alt=""/> 
    Login
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Javascript is inserted in to the page (as mentioned by Curt) which was not a problem for me but may be for other people; but since the `asp:loginview` and other controls associated with forms authentication already need javascript I'm not sure this is a problem with the solution.

I decided to accept jwiscarson's answer as this is a cleaner implementation and, despite what I thought, `<button>` can be a drop-in replacement for `<asp:button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question:

> if the asp:button can be replaced and still call the LoginButton_Click C# code behind?

is yes. If you have a button like:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="positive" runat="server">Submit</button>
```

The attribute you need to set is **not** `onclick`, but `onserverclick`. You could also do something like:

```
protected override OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    submit.ServerClick += new EventHandler(submit_ServerClick);
}
```

If you need to do styling on that button, I think the best way to tackle that is via CSS classes like you have in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You may set `CSS` class via  `cssClass` property of `<asp:Button/>`. However you may set `runat="server"` and `onserverclick="LoginButton_Click"` attribute to `<button/>`.

Comment: Styling options for an `<input type="button" />` are pretty limited though.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to make use the LinkButton control and style that completely with CSS. We used to do so for a certain project in the past. Worked out pretty great for our customer.

The property of interest if **[CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx)**

Comment: Only problem with this is that LinkButtons don't work without javascript. OP hasn't specified this, but its worth taking into account.

Comment: @Curt - I don't mind using javascript, I'm mainly interested in achieving a nice looking button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML button if you desire, and learn how to call the `__doPostBack()` method with the proper arguments. Asp.Net buttons and HTML buttons are pretty much the same when it comes to the way they are rendered in the client.

Answer (score 0):

As had been posted here already you could style the HTML rendered by your `asp:button` or use another asp control. Your `asp:button` will be rendered as a `<input type="submit">` with possibly more limited CSS options than a `<button>` tag.

From some googling I think it is possible to get a `<button>` tag rendered but it looks like a non trivial excercise see [How can I use the button tag with ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187482/how-can-i-use-the-button-tag-with-asp-net)

Comment: Interesting link, for all my searching of SO before posting my question I didn't manage to find that one! Thanks, I'll take a look.